# unable to login with the credentials of user who does not have an appid for facebook application in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

Am trying to login to my facebook app. created with c#.net and silverlight. here, I am sending a request containing appid that I have requested from the facebook sdk to login to my application which is successful with my facebook credentials where as no other user is able to  login in to my application with their facebook credentials.

```
 Enums.ExtendedPermissions[] permissions = { Enums.ExtendedPermissions.publish_stream, 
                                                      Enums.ExtendedPermissions.read_stream, 
                                                      Enums.ExtendedPermissions.create_event, 
                                                      Enums.ExtendedPermissions.create_note, 
                                                      Enums.ExtendedPermissions.photo_upload, 
                                                      Enums.ExtendedPermissions.read_mailbox, 
                                                      Enums.ExtendedPermissions.manage_mailbox, 
                                                      Enums.ExtendedPermissions.share_item, Enums.ExtendedPermissions.video_upload};



        Session = new BrowserSession("MyAppId");

        Session.LoginCompleted += browserSession_LoginCompleted;
        Session.LogoutCompleted += browserSession_LogoutCompleted;
```

please let me know the way to resolve my issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app public?

If your don't want it to be public yet, you have to add the other users.
In the developers.facebook.com page, you can add users as testers, admins etc. to your app. You can find this section by your app and then Roles. I think your the only one standing in the role section now.